# Use grid layout to achieve the fixed position on the left browser doubts?

Tags: css, grid

Recently studying the grid layout, [layout in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7twt.png), my own realization is as follows:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  /*   display: inline-grid; */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "m b i t" "m s s s" "m c c c";
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0px;
  grid-area: m;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: coral;
  grid-area: b;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: beige;
  grid-area: i;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
  grid-area: t;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-5 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  grid-area: s;
}

.item-6 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  grid-area: c;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="header">this is header</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-1">clo 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">col 2</div>
    <div class="item-3">col 3</div>
    <div class="item-4">col 4</div>
    <div class="item-5">
      <h2>this is 44</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-6">
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>this is footer</footer>
</div>
```

However, I have encountered a problem now and I have tried hard to meditate for a few days. I can not understand why, and I hope everyone can help:

For the left `item1`, is a fixed effect of the fixed screen height and height of the browser, but if I use the `grid` to do the layout, there is no way to achieve the fixed effect on the left, how to solve it? (Because of the responsive layout, the `item1` will be hidden after the screen is smaller than a certain size, and the `menu` button will be displayed)

Thank you very much for any help in resolving any doubts

Answer (score 0):

You could use `position: sticky` instead of `fixed`.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  /*   display: inline-grid; */
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 15px 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "m b i t" "m s s s" "m c c c";
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0px;
  grid-area: m;
  /* added */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: coral;
  grid-area: b;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: beige;
  grid-area: i;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: darkturquoise;
  grid-area: t;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.item-5 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  grid-area: s;
}

.item-6 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
  grid-area: c;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="header">this is header</header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item-1">clo 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">col 2</div>
    <div class="item-3">col 3</div>
    <div class="item-4">col 4</div>
    <div class="item-5">
      <h2>this is 44</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item-6">
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
      <h1>123123</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>this is footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Before I trying to locate `item1` in the grid using `fixed` and `sticky`, but after reducing the screen size.
I need to hide the item outside the left screen and slide it through the button, but setting the `left` property is not available.
Is there any good way, thank you.